# C# Blazor server Azure AD auth setup with Web API and graph token

Tags: c#, blazor

i have an issue with my c# blazor server setup.

I am fairly new to the .net eco system and I have a problem I can not figure out on my own. I hope any of you can help me.

I have a blazor server setup with Azure AD Authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

When the user has autheticated, I can get an access token with the following code:

```
var token = new TokenProvider
        {
            AccessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")
        };
```

I use this token to call the Microsoft Web API to fetch customers from Dynamics CRM, with the following setup:

```
// Setup client
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme,
                opt =>
                {
                    var resourceUri = new Uri(Configuration["CDSAPI"]);
                    var resource = $"{resourceUri.Scheme}://{resourceUri.Host}/";
                    opt.ResponseType = "code";
                    opt.SaveTokens = true;
                    opt.Scope.Add("user_impersonation");
                    opt.Scope.Add(new Uri(Configuration["CDSAPI"]).Host);
                    opt.Resource = resource;
                });

            services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();
            services.AddHttpClient("CDS", client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["CDSAPI"]);
            });
```

I then use this client in my code to fetch the customers:

```
try
        {
            var client = Factory.CreateClient("CDS");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", TokenProvider.AccessToken);
            var result = await client.GetStringAsync("accounts?$select=name&$orderby=name");

            DynamicsCustomerEntity customerCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DynamicsCustomerEntity>(result);
            customers = customerCollection.value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
```

This works fine. But the issue presents itself when I try to implement Microsoft Graph functionality.

For example, if I try to use this code:

```
services.AddMicrosoftWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
        .AddMicrosoftWebAppCallsWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { "Calendars.Read", "Calendars.ReadWrite" })
        .AddDistributedTokenCaches();
 
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                         .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

instead of

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

I can no longer access the token with

```
await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")
```

So my question is:

How can I make a blazor server setup to get two valid tokens - one for Graph API calls and one for Microsoft Web API calls? I need delegated permission tokens for both.

I hope my question makes sence. I have tried to provide as much context as possible.

Thanks in advance.